# C++ namespace "first defined here" bug?

Tags: c++, sfml

So I'm having this weird bug when compiling. I've provided a image of the bug at the bottom of this post, and alternatively you can view the bug list here: http://puu.sh/7EzYk.txt

Code:

```
#ifndef CFO_HPP
#define CFO_HPP

#include <string>
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

class Res
{
    public:
        // Methods
        std::string getWord(std::string l, int x);
        std::string getWords(std::string l, int x, int y);
        int getWordCount(std::string l);
};

class shell;

namespace cfo
{
    // Variables
    static std::string version = "- Alpha [0.1]";
    static int screenshot = 0;

    // Classes
    Res res; // Tools etc.
    //shell config;
    //shell gfx;

    // Methods
    void screenshoter(sf::RenderWindow &window);
};

void cfo::screenshoter(sf::RenderWindow &window) // This was in a .cpp file, but I moved it here.
{
    sf::Image screen = window.capture();
    screen.saveToFile(screenshot + ".jpg");
    screenshot++;
}

#endif
```

BUG IMAGE: http://puu.sh/7EzG9.png

Comment: That's not the error, only part of it. The error is that you've violated the One Definition Rule.

Comment: I think I've figured part of it out. I have multiple files including the header in the code. How can I have multiple files include something, but only define the namespace once?

Comment: The namespace isn't the problem, but you should declare things in headers and define them in implementation files.

Comment: Ahh so, when I defined the "res" object. I should have done that in the namespaces .cpp file?

Comment: @user Yes. Also the function definition.